# How to change bakground color opacity TapBar?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I need to make the bar transparent and you can see the background view. 
How can I do this? Or better to use a picture instead of color?

```swift
struct TapBarMenu: View {
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.init(red: 0, green: 174, blue: 180,alpha: 1)
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
    }

    var body: some View {
        TabView{

            MainMenu().tabItem({
                Image(systemName: "house")
                Text("Home")

            }).accentColor(Color.red)
            SearchView().tabItem({
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass.circle")
                Text("Search")

            }).accentColor(Color.red)
            MessagesView().tabItem({
                Image(systemName: "message")
                Text("Message")

            }).accentColor(Color.red)
            ProfileView().tabItem({
                Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                Text("Profile")

            }).accentColor(Color.red)

        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the **standardAppearance** attributes of the tabBar with and extension of UITabBarController:

```
extension UITabBarController {
    override open func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
        tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    }
}
```